# Conditional expectation and exchangeability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose that $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are exchangeable real-valued random variables. Let $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be Borel measurable functions. For $i \neq j$, is it true that

> $$ \mathbb{E} \Big[ f \Big( \mathbb{E} \big[  g(X_i) \Big| X_j \big]  \Big) \Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ f \Big( \mathbb{E} \big[ g(X_j) \Big| X_i \big] \Big) \Big] ?$$

This result would hold, by the definition of exchangeability, IF we can show that for any random variables $X$ and $Y$,$$\mathbb{E} \big[ g(X) \Big| Y \big] = h(X, Y),$$ for some Borel measurable function $h : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. But is this statement true? Most standard texts only prove that 
$$\mathbb{E} \big[ g(X) \Big| Y \big] = h^{(X)}( Y),$$
for some Borel measurable function $h^{(X)} : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that depends on $X$.

Comment: Indeed, $E(g(X)\mid Y)=h(Y)$ where $h$ depends on the function $g$ and the distribution of $(X,Y)$ only. This yields the result you ask about, since $(X_i,X_j)$ and $(X_j,X_i)$ have the same distribution.

Comment: Five months later... got something from the comment above?